# RailsTutorial member system--cookie is different from the remember token in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, railstutorial.org, digest-authentication

First of all: I have already tried googling this under a few terms: "remember token different from cookie rails", "current_user nil:nilClass", "remember_token not working rails", and "current_user is nil rails" (you can probably see I have two different problems here, but I think one is caused by the other). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709472/rails-tutorial-cookie-doesnt-match-remember-token), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354993/rails-sign-inuser-not-working-remember-token), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811419/why-am-i-getting-error-undefined-method-name-for-nilnilclass-with-ruby-on-rai) didn't answer my problem; there are numerous others that didn't either.

When I try to register a new user, I get an error of "NoMethodError: undefined method 'name' for nil:nilClass" after it goes through. Now, the user *is* being created, but it isn't getting signed in. The `remember_token` attribute in the database is not the same as (and also is longer than) the `remember_token` cookie. When I attempt to log in, the flash appears with a message of 'you must log in to do that' (the message I have set for restricted access) and I get directed to the `/login` page again. The most recent thing I did was add a `terms_of_service` checkbox and a validation for it; I removed this and the problem persists.

You can see my code [here](https://gist.github.com/Alonessix/5a060126bc25d6b51c8a).

The cookie remember token: EEBlz7wM_-9jo-YQ47D8-g
The digested cookie remember token: 7c96d144956bbbaa6294137555a709b0cfefdd1d
And finally, the remember token in the database (already digested): ddebfafb628ab141a6db84d42fb13355fad83fb1

I know this is said a lot, but I *have* been trying to figure this out for a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind about this--got it done on my own. It turned out that I was using `before_save` instead of `before_create` with the whole `:create_remember_token` thing. Somehow not using `update_attributes` fixed it; `update_attribute` twice works.